# UPDATE all empty array columns to be NULL

Tags: mysql

MySQL query is:

```
UPDATE buddy SET buddy_positions = CONCAT('| ',
       (IF(buddy1_request = 'Yes', 'buddy1_main | ','')),
       (IF(buddy2_request = 'Yes','buddy2_main | ','')),
       (IF(buddy3_request = 'Yes','buddy3_main | ','')),
       (IF(buddy4_request = 'Yes' NULL,'buddy4_main | ','')),
       (IF(buddy5_request = 'Yes','buddy5_main | ','')))
```

My problem is that if buddy1_request = 'Yes' I want it to CONCAT the data in a separate cell (buddy1_main) plus some extra bits. I'm struggling to output the result from another column however, I can type it in manually but can't find a way to do this automatically.

**EDIT**

So my data looks like this:

|buddy1_request | buddy1_main | buddy2_request | buddy2_main |buddy_position|

|---------------|-------------|----------------|-------------|--------------|

|Yes            |prop         |no              |NULL         |(CONCAT HERE) |

So what I want to happen is that if buddy1_request says 'Yes' then it includes the contents of buddy1_main in the CONCAT for buddy_position and so on

In this example the output would simpley be "prop", however if buddy2_request said "Yes" it would have a value such as "winger" and the CONCAT would return "prop","winger"

My problem is that my current query returns the text "buddy1_main","buddy2_main"

I don't know how to reference the column and pull the value through in the CONCAT.

**PS** I don't see how this is bad design, it's a table where player adds a friend and if they click yes to playing with them that week it brings through their position as well into buddy1_main, I then need a way of outputting all the results into a table for clubs to view so they know that player also comes with X amount of people that can platy positions X,Y and Z.

However if player 2 is unavailable but player 4 is available it needs to ignore player 2's position. I hope that makes sense, there's  a lot of reasons it's done this way and it's actually a very complex system when you drill down into it all. I've kept it this way so it's modular and not linear as a model so I can change aspects to it as needed without having a knock on effect. I'm not concerned about how memory hungry it is on the server at this stage.

Comment: What is that NULL with the 'Yes' doing?  Also give some sample data and what you expect to happen vs to what is happening

Comment: I'm looking to those columns names and I can't stop to think that this is a bad database design...

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design

Comment: Apologies fell asleep! I'll edit question now with what is happening and what I want to happen.